# JSON response displayed as plain text on submission when creating/editing an entry

Tags: debugging

I am running Craft Pro 2.2.2601. When I submit an entry, I am getting back JSON rather than being redirected to a success page.

For example, I just go to:

```
/admin/entries/pages/new
```

I fill out some fields and click `Save`. It kicks me to the next page that displays JSON as the source as opposed to an "Entry saved" flash message:

```
{"success":true,"title":"Services","cpEditUrl":"http:\/\/www.test123.com\/admin\/entries\/pages\/22-services","author":{"id":"1","enabled":"1","archived":"0","locale":"en_us","localeEnabled":true,"slug":null,"uri":null,"dateCreated":{"date":"2014-11-04 15:44:04","timezone_type":1,"timezone":"+00:00"},"dateUpdated":{"date":"2014-11-04 15:44:04","timezone_type":1,"timezone":"+00:00"},"root":null,"lft":null,"rgt":null,"level":null,"username":"test123","photo":null,"firstName":null,"lastName":null,"email":"test123@gmail.com","preferredLocale":null,"admin":"1","client":"0","status":"active","lastLoginDate":{"date":"2014-11-07 02:01:58","timezone_type":1,"timezone":"+00:00"},"invalidLoginCount":null,"lastInvalidLoginDate":null,"lockoutDate":null,"passwordResetRequired":"0","lastPasswordChangeDate":{"date":"2014-11-04 15:44:04","timezone_type":1,"timezone":"+00:00"},"unverifiedEmail":null,"newPassword":null,"currentPassword":null,"verificationCodeIssuedDate":null},"postDate":"11\/6\/2014"}
```

The page also contains the posted data, so refreshing re-submits the form post. I have disabled JS compression and it worked once (got the "Entry saved" flash message), but now it is back to spitting out JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on MediaTemple?

http://buildwithcraft.com/help/forms-returning-json

Comment: Correct! I apologize... I have no idea how I missed that help topic. I am already starting to dislike MT.